# Get Page instance externally in WinRT

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I am currently developing a Windows 8 App which contains 2 pages(`page1` , `page2`).

After navigating form page1 to page2,
using `this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(AnotherPage));`
 how can i access the instance of `page2` form `page1`,(***We can implement it by having a static instance property and set it when the constructor is called*** )

But is there any in-build feature to access the current instance of the page from outside of the current page, Or is this pattern of programming is recommended in WinRT paradigms, is there any way to implement my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is - by default the instance of the previous page is not kept in memory after you navigate to the next page by default - not unless you change the default NavigationCacheMode of the page, which might not be a good idea unless the page takes a lot of time to load and is like a hub page that you go back to a lot.

The approach I would suggest is to use the [MVVM](http://blog.xyzzer.me/2012/08/27/minimalistic-mvvm-for-windows-runtime-xaml-platform-development-with-c/) pattern, so pages never have to talk to each other and it's the view models that would do it. Then use a pub/sub pattern with a helper like the Messenger class in MVVM Light Toolkit to send weak events/messages instead of adding tight coupling between objects.

All in all - it depends on what you want to do and why you want your pages to talk to each other. You could pass a parameter in the Navigate() call (make sure it's just a primitive type though if you want to support app suspensions using the SuspensionManager class and built-in serialization from the Frame class). You could also use some sort of a global repository or settings service to share data between pages.

If you're not willing to invest in these things - using the plain old static class might be enough for you. Whatever works.